# Why did my program stop working when I eject the serial cable like it did an auto reset?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-ide, reset

Arduino Uno based on 328p micro-controller board only works while I am inserting the serial cable between the board and the computer and I can control the speed of my two motors and every thing is work properly, but when I eject the serial cable it works badly and there is no control, is that some thing occurs like auto Reset?

There is always 5 volt feeding the Arduino, I get 5 volt regulated from the battery using "5v regulator", this regulated voltage is always connected to the Arduino board.

Comment: What is powering the arduino when its not connected to the computer? the arduino might be browning out without the usb power.

Comment: there is always 5 volt feeds  the arduino, i get 5 volt regulated from the battery using "5v regulator", this regulated voltage always connected to the arduino board.

Comment: 5V is good, but it's not enough. Power (in this context, current) matters.
You mention 2 motors. Those things tend to draw relatively a lot of current.
Are you sure that the battery you are using can support the power requirements of the system?

Comment: @lgor Stoppa my 2 Motors feeding directly from the battery which  is 11.30 v, i know that I have just to feeds the arduino  by 5v.so no relation between the number of Motors I use.

Comment: Yes you can use the 12V battery I have found this in th Arduino Uno specs: Input Voltage (recommended) 7-12V
Input Voltage (limit) 6-20V

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the voltage of the power supply. Maybe there might be a problem with the current. The Arduino has a 5V regulator on-board, try using a 9V battery. MAKE SURE THAT YOU CONNECT TO THE DC BARREL CONNECTOR.

Good luck!

Comment: can I use 12V Battery to Feeds The arduino.

Comment: @omran You should be able to.

Comment: If you have a problem with current, a 9V battery doesn't supply much (current).